# Using CSS to vertically rotate from it's original top left not the center axis

Tags: html, css, rotation

How do you vertically rotate text on IE8+

The elements I want to vertically rotate are positioned absolutely and require to be in the same place.

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child_1">
   </div>

   <div id="child_2">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}

#child_1 {
postion: absolute;
top: 250px;
left: 50px;
width: 100px;
height: 10px;
}

#child_2 {
postion: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 10px;
width: 100px;
height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: CSS transforms are not supported in IE8. In IE9+ you can use the CSS3 property `transform-origin: top left;`

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hack for IE8 using filter however this requires positioning of element for IE separately but I can live with this.

IE8:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

IE9+:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
```